# Status bar in iOS getting darker by itself

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set the status bar color using below code but its getting 1 tone darker by itself

```
extension UIViewController {

  func setStatusBar(backgroundColor: UIColor) {
      let statusBarFrame: CGRect
      if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
          statusBarFrame = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero
      } else {
          statusBarFrame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
      }
      let statusBarView = UIView(frame: statusBarFrame)
      statusBarView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
      view.addSubview(statusBarView)
  }
```

}

[image]
[image]

I verified all the things. the view below has 1.0 alpha. there is no overlay on the status bar.
How can I make it same color?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this was an issue from XCode.
I set the same colour with exact same values in swift instead of Storyboard and it worked very well.

Confirmed the same in multiple view controller.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarUIView: UIView? {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let tag = 38482
            let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
            
            if let statusBar = keyWindow?.viewWithTag(tag) {
                return statusBar
            } else {
                guard let statusBarFrame = keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame else { return nil }
                let statusBarView = UIView(frame: statusBarFrame)
                statusBarView.tag = tag
                keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBarView)
                return statusBarView
            }
        } else if responds(to: Selector(("statusBar"))) {
            return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarUIView?.backgroundColor = .red
```

Comment: No luck. still one tone dark. from where this is getting dark color, I don't know.

Comment: Is there any other way through which I can make it the same color as the view below?

Comment: I use this in my projects I think the place where you call this function matters
try in ViewDidAppear